# Material View is all Black and White, no shading

Tags: modeling

All of my objects in my material view are now black and white, I have no idea what I did.. The black objects have materials that were working. Why is this happening?! [image]

Comment: Hard to say if we don't know anything about your material setup. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Comment: I had to switch from Cycles to Evee and then delete lighting cache.